# Utilizing my old Physical Server

Tags: nfs, iscsi

I have one question regarding a shared storage, hopefully, someone will help to choose. Long story short, I have an old Dell R710 server (Windows 2012) with a bunch of disks (6x2TB 7,2k NLSAS in Raid-10) which is utilizing right now as the fileserver. Currently, all my infrastructure is mixed, so I have 2 ESXi server which is running some VMs (such as exchange, AD, etc.) for my company. So my plan is to virtualize my fileserver and use all capacity of my physical box (R710) as the shared storage to my ESXi. I have found this article (http://www.hyper-v.io/whos-got-bigger-balls-testing-nfs-vs-iscsi-performance-part-1-configuring-nfs/) about NFS vs. iSCSI and I just wondering which protocol is better to use for my situation? Thank you! P.S. I plan to add a 10 GB links to my boxes to achieve maximum performance.